# Subconsulta mysql no correcta

Tags: mysql, sql

Soy un estudiante de informatica el cual en estos momentos es aficionado, estoy ejecutando varias consultas que se me han presentado. En este caso tengo el siguiente enunciado:

```
-- 11. Seleccionar id y nombre de los programas de la categoria 'Blogs'. 
-- Utilizar una subconsulta
```

Como output ha de dar la siguiente salida

```
/*
 +-+--+---------------+
 | |id|nombre         |
 +-+--+---------------+
 |1| 1|Elgg 1.7.5     |
 +-+--+---------------+
 |2| 2|WordPress 3.0.1|
 +-+--+---------------+
*/
```

Es una consulta bastante bàsica, el problema es que solo me muestra el primer row de salida y no consigo que me muestre el segundo row de "Wordpress".

La consulta que he hecho es:

```
select id, nombre from programas where id = (select id from categorias where nombre like 'Blogs');
```

Y las tablas están formadas de la siguiente forma:

```
categorias
----------->id 
----------->nombre

programas
----------->id
----------->categoria_id
----------->icono
----------->nombre
----------->web
----------->url_descarga
----------->descripcion
```

(Entre otras tablas que hay en la base de datos pero que creo que no són necesarias)

Comment: Debes remplazar el signo = de " where id = " por "where id in " por  in

Comment: ¿Y si pruebas de esta forma: `SELECT programas.id, programas.nombre
FROM programas 
WHERE categoria_id IN (SELECT id FROM categorias WHERE categorias.nombre = 'Blog');`?

Comment: Además considera que no es el id de programas el valor a usar en el where sino el categoria_id pues esta columna es la que te vincula como llave foránea con la tabla `categorias`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder usar el **operador de igualdad (=)** en una subconsulta esta debe retornar un solo registro, si retorna más de un registro la subconsulta, entonces habrá un error, esto ocurre con todos los **operadores relacionales(=,>,<,>=,<=)**, en caso de que la subconsulta devuelva más de un registro pues deberás usar según corresponda los **operadores** **in** o **not in**. En tu caso es el **in**, el cual busca si el campo de la consulta original está contenido en el resultado que devuelve la subconsulta. Ahora tu consulta quedaría así:

```
select id, nombre 
from programas 
where categoria_id in (select id 
                       from categorias  
                       where nombre like 'Blogs'
                      );
```

Además, el campo por el que debes comparar en la **tabla programas** es **categoria_id** y no **id**, revisa bien esto.